# Another duplicity instance is already running with this archive directory

Tags: ubuntu, duplicity, backups

I get this message when i try to back up my ubuntu desktop with Duplicity ...

> Another duplicity instance is already running with this archive directory

My Duplicity version is...

```
dara@laptop-20-04:~/git_repos/olf_git$ duplicity --version
duplicity 0.8.12
```

My ubuntu version is...

```
dara@laptop-20-04:~/git_repos/olf_git$ uname -a
Linux laptop-20-04 5.4.0-52-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm backing up to Google Drive.

I'm guessing there's a lock file or runaway process issue maybe?

Also, how do I access individual files from my Duplicity backup? Without doing a Full Restore? I only see incremental tar.gz files in the Duplicity backup folders.

Answer (score 1):

system seems to right itself somehow.

i'm guessing that maybe a system restart or TTL on the lockfile ran out and it got deleted automatically.

Anyway seems to work fine now. I'd try a system restart if you are having the same issues. Either that or look for the duplicity lockfile.